# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, localhost, varnish

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] returns 127.0.0.1.

is that because I installed varnish cache and data goes to varnish, then apache, and server think request came from varnish not client?

Comment: I don't know about Varnish but that might be the case.. I had this problem when using nginx as a load balancer.. just print_r the $_SERVER superglobal.. you will find the IP in a different field..like X_FORWARDED_FOR

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Get the remote ip address like this:

```
public function getRemoteIPAddress() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { 
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but this is bad advice. See [@Ka.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37254156/2032498). Also, `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` can come from the client and is therefore unreliable. In general, first make sure that `REMOTE_ADDR` is a trusted host. And only then you can rely on further HTTP headers like `X_FORWARDED_FOR`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28217316/2343242 has code to just grab the first ip address listed by `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Answer (score 3):

Beware, $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] can contain multiple ips, see [How do I get the correct IP from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR if it contains multiple IP Addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753645/how-do-i-get-the-correct-ip-from-http-x-forwarded-for-if-it-contains-multiple-ip)