# C# not showing the full IP address

Tags: javascript, c#

I am having some issues getting the full IP address with C#. When I call a C# web method via a button click, it displays (or should) the IP address in a JavaScript alert box. What I am getting instead of the IP address is ::1. I am running this via Visual Studio 2015 Community. Here is my code:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string getIPAddress()
    {
        // this method gets the ip address by using the server variables 
        // in C# to capture the data from the client
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
            {
                return addresses[0];
            }
        }

        return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
```

And the method that handles the button click:

```
   // display the ip address to the user if the button is clicked (display it via a javascript alert box)
    public void IpAddress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Data d = new Data();

        Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + d.getIPAddress() + "');</script>");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That is a full IP address; it's IPv6 localhost.

Comment: is there any way to get the IPv4 address or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

is not necessarily getting you the client's IP address, depending on your network setup.  The X_FORWARDED_FOR header is optionally added by proxy servers between you and the browser.  There can be many IP addresses listed, or none at all if there were no (well-behaved) proxy servers in the connection path.  The format of the actual header is

X-Forwarded-For: client1, proxy1, proxy2, ...

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753804/141172))

The address ::1 is the IPv6 loopback address.  It's not possible to know why the header is populated with ::1 without further understanding your network architecture.

If you just want to get the client's IP address, use

Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]

Note that this is not 100% reliable, as some proxies will substitute their own IP address and *not* populate the X-Forwarded-For header (AOL is infamous for this, but there are many other examples).

> is there any way to get the IPv4 address or is that not possible?

Not every piece of hardware is still assigned an IPv4 address, though as a practical matter, most still are.  If you could get the IPv4 address, it would be 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Comment: it's running from the built in IIS server with visual studio community 2015