# Getting client ip in apache

Tags: apache, logging, centos, httpd.conf

Here is my logging config:

```
LogFormat "{\
\"time\":%{sec}t,\
\"clientip\":\"%{CLIENTIP}e\",\
\"status\":%>s,\
\"request_method\":\"%m\",\
\"jsessionid\":\"%{JSESSIONID}C\",\
\"uniqueid\":\"%{X-Unique-Id}i\",\
\"request_processing_time\":%D,\
\"sent_bytes\":%B,\
\"request_uri_query\":\"%q\",\
\"referer\":\"%{Referer}i\",\
\"request_uri_path\":\"%U\",\
\"virtual_host\":\"%{Host}i\",\
\"user_agent\":\"%{User-agent}i\",\
\"request_http_version\":\"%H\",\
\"node\":\"%{HOSTNAME}e\",\
\"x-forwarded-for\": \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\"\
}" my_logs_json
```

I need to get only the left most ip address from x-forwarded-for. Is there a way I can get it in apache ?
What I have tried is [Get correct IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753645/how-do-i-get-the-correct-ip-from-http-x-forwarded-for-if-it-contains-multiple-ip?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it hasn't worked for me or I am doing it wrong.

***Update***

I have been doing it wrong. I needed to pass the variable I had set in the vhost as described in the Get correct IP post, in the LogFormat instead of "%{X-Forwarded-For}i".

Comment: have you tried mod_remoteip and %a in logformat?

Comment: Hi @ezra-s ,Actually I have been able to resolve the issue. I had forgot to update the post.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not passing name of the variable I had set in the vhost and instead I was leaving "%{X-Forwarded-For}i" as it is. Added variable name instead of this and it solved the issue.