# MVC4 Web Api Client IP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm looking for a way to get the client ip address inside controller. I've tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`. This returns me `::1`. Right now the Webserver is running on localhost and the requst is from localhost, too. Will this method work after deploying ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will work.Now it is returing localhost in IP 6 format.

There are only a few things you should remember about:

1. If user is behind NAT or proxy it will show IP of NAT/proxy
2. There is a discussion about more problems with wrong IP [UserHostAddress gives wrong IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200527/userhostaddress-gives-wrong-ips)