# get Client public Ip address in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i am using an service to get client country based on the ip address but it is made through web api rest service when i used **UserHostAddress** it shows internal ip only when i send this to service it is showing wrong country is there any solution to get country or ipaddresss

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Did you call the server from an internal IP? `UserHostAddress` displays the IP that the server sees. If the client is behind a NAT firewall, this will be the "public" IP. Otherwise, it's the client's actual IP. The server doesn't know nor care what that address is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UserHostAddress gives wrong IPs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200527/userhostaddress-gives-wrong-ips)

Comment: Can you try, `string SourceIP = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];`

Answer (score 0):

If you have local ip, and your router has the real one, your computer only communicates with router, and router communicates with Internet. There are two ways of getting routers IP:

1. Send http request to some site that shows your IP and get it from there.
2. Connect to router interface and get IP directly from router.